# Combinatorics: Bona 3rd ed chapter 5: Partitions

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that for all positive integers k $\le$ n, the inequality $p_k(n)$ $\le$ $(n-k+1)^{(k-1)}$  holds.

Is it true that $p_k(n)$ is a polynomial function of n?

(Number 29 chapter 5)
I don't even know where to start with the first part of this inequality proof.

Answer (score 1):

Each summand is at most $n - k + 1$, 'cause other $k-1$ summands are positive. So you have at most $n - k + 1$ variants for each summand. But if you know first $k-1$ of them you definitely know the last one. So the number of different not greater than $(n - k + 1)^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Smylic has answered the first question; for the second, determine $p_2(n)$ explicitly as a function of $n$ and show that this function is not a polynomial.

Comment: Brian, we tried to use induction to prove that it IS true. Could you provide a little more advice on how this is not a polynomial

Comment: @user101104: Have you determined exactly what $p_2(n)$ is as a function of $n$? The function $f(n)=p_2(2n)$ is a polynomial in $n$, but $p_2(n)$ is not.

Comment: The only thing we've got is that $p_2(n)$ is n/2 when it's even and n-1/2 when it's odd.

Comment: @user101104: Exactly: and that function cannot be written as a polynomial. It isn’t a linear function, and if $f(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ or more, you can prove that there is an $m$ such that $f(n)>p_2(n)$ for all $n\ge m$, so it’s not a higher degree polynomial, either.

Comment: Okay, so this disproves by contradiction for the k=2 case  and I know that is sufficient to disprove but is there anyway to generalize for $p_k(n)$

Comment: @user101104: Yes, by induction on $k$. From the recurrence $p_k(n)=p_{k-1}(n-1)+p_k(n-k)$ we get $p_{k-1}(n-1)=p_k(n)-p_k(n-k)$. If $p_k(n)$ were a polynomial, the function $p_k(n)-p_k(n-k)$ would also be a polynomial, so $p_{k-1}(n-1)$ and hence also $p_{k-1}(n)$ would be a polynomial.